# Built-in version properties for log4j and lombok

Tags: spring-boot, maven, log4j2, lombok

I have found some sample maven pom.xml files that use "built-in" properties to specify the versions for logj42 and lombok. However, I cannot find where these properties are documented?  If I didn't know I could use these properties, where could I look to see what "custom" properties are supported by a given package?

How can I find that log4j2 supports a "log4j2.version" property and lombok supports a "lombok.version" property? These are part of a Spring Boot application, are these properties associated with Spring Boot?

Example:

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

   <properties>
        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: simply add a dependency with the appropriate coordinates https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.16.0/jar and use the most recent version....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties `lombok.version` and `log4j2.version` have no special meaning for Maven nor any of its plugins.

These properties are defined in the parent POM ([`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies)) of your parent project ([`spring-boot-starter-parent`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent)) and are used to perform variable substitutions of the form `${log4j2.version}` in the same file.

Download the [`spring-boot-dependencies` POM file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.1/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.1.pom) to see the names of hundreds of other properties defined in that file. As you already noticed, you can override their value in your own `pom.xml`.

Comment: The dependency versions and version-override properties are also documented for each Spring Boot release. For Spring Boot 2.6.1, the documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions